# "malloc(): corrupted top size" when constructing vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create this function:

```cpp
std::vector<int> graph::getNeighbors(int n){
    int i = 0; for(int el : verteces[n]) i++;

    if( i != 0){
        auto iter = verteces[n].begin();
        std::vector<int> res = std::vector<int>{i};
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            res[j] = *(iter++);
        return res;
    }

    return std::vector<int>{};
}
```

As the name itself explain, it is supposed to get the neighbors of a vertex. The graph is made like this:

```cpp
class graph {
private:
    std::vector<std::forward_list<int>> verteces;
    unsigned long int n;
    ···
};
```

Now, the problem is that whenever `i` is greater than 0, the program crashes badly with the error:

> malloc(): corrupted top size

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

## EDIT

In order to make a reproducible example I am going to show all the three files.

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include "graph/graph.h"

void greedyAlgorithm(graph &G){
    std::vector<int> colors{static_cast<int>(G.getSize())};
    for(int i=0; i<G.getSize(); i++)
        colors[i] = -1;


    for(int i=0; i<G.getSize(); i++){ // for each vertex
        std::set<int> colorNeigh{};
        for(auto &j : G.getNeighbors(i)){
            if(colors[j] != -1)
                colorNeigh.insert( colors[j] );
        }

        int col = 0;
        for(auto &el : colorNeigh){
            if(el == col) col++;
            else break;
        }
        colors[i] = col;
    }


}

int main() {
    {
        std::vector<int> r;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            r.push_back(i);
    }

    graph a = graph(10);

    a.addEdge(2, 5);
    a.addEdge(2, 5);
    a.addEdge(1,2);
    a.addEdge(2,3);
    a.addEdge(3,4);

    greedyAlgorithm(a);

    return 0;
}
```

graph.h:

```cpp
//
// Created by salvo on 11/08/21.
//

#ifndef P2_GRAPH_H
#define P2_GRAPH_H

#include <forward_list>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class node;

// list implementation
class graph {
private:
    std::vector<std::forward_list<int>> verteces;
    unsigned long int n;

public:
    graph();
    graph(unsigned long int n); // vertex number

    void addEdge(int a, int b);
    std::vector<int> getNeighbors(int n);

    unsigned long getSize(){return n;};
};

#endif //P2_GRAPH_H
```

graph.cpp:

```cpp
//
// Created by salvo on 11/08/21.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/ossl_typ.h>
#include "graph.h"

graph::graph() {
    // verteces call default constructor
    n = 0;
}

graph::graph(unsigned long int n) {
    verteces = std::vector<std::forward_list<int>>{n};
    for(auto &el : verteces) el = std::forward_list<int>{};
    this->n = n;
}

void graph::addEdge(int a, int b) {
    if(a == b){
        std::cout << " No self loop!\nexiting ";
        exit(-2);
    }

    int m = a > b ? a : b + 1;
    if(m > n){
        std::cout << "The graph only contains " << n << " verteces.\n exiting.";
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Check if the edge exist already
    for(auto &el : verteces[a]){
        if(el == b) return;
    }

    verteces[a].emplace_front(b);
    verteces[b].emplace_front(a);
    std::cout << verteces.size() << std::endl;
}

std::vector<int> graph::getNeighbors(int n){
    std::vector<int> res{};

    for(auto el : verteces[n])
        res.push_back(el);

    return res;
}
```

Output if executed:

```
malloc(): corrupted top size

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I am using C++14.

Comment: Did you try any debugger?  What is the purpose of the first for-range? to calculate `verteces` size? why you don't use `std::vector::size`? The crash is properly for `res[j] = *(iter++);`.

Comment: `std::vector<int>{i}` creates a vector with a single element -- e.g. `res.size()` will return `1`.  Did you mean `std::vector<int>(i)` instead?

Comment: If you do `for(int el : verteces[n]) i++;` over the `forward_list` a lot you may want to use a different container that actually has a `size()` member function.

Comment: That entire function is overkill and can be reduced to a single expression: `std::vector<int> graph::getNeighbors(int n){ return std::vector<int>(verteces[n].begin(), verteces[n].end()); }`

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Yes, I am using gdb. The size I'm trying to calculate is the size of a forward list

Comment: @user4581301 What do you mean "Can we prove vertices is a std::vector? You have the definition of vertices as defined in the class graph.

Comment: @jspkay You really need to check the documentation and examples before starting to codding.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know. I am trying to start simple. The original code wasn't like this but similar results were reproduced.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. I have two problems with that: 
1. Clion doesn't find any viable constructor
2. Neither do I in this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

    Can you tell which one you are talking about?

Comment: You can replace all code in `getNeighbors` with a single line using `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Believe me, I am doing that. I started three hours ago. I'll share my original version.

Comment: @jspkay constructor #5, which accepts a range of values denoted by iterators: `template< class InputIt > vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you once again. I tried. I've got the same error, as better explained in the edit of the original post. It's really weird to me. I don't understand what's the problem. I mean, I called the constructor and nothing more.

Comment: This error means your program corrupted memory at some point in the past. Your program overwrote some memory it wasn't supposed to, and it only got detected when the program tried to allocate some more.

Comment: @jspkay your original code [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/aaorSb) after changing `std::vector<int>{i}` to `std::vector<int>(i)`.  And the code I showed you [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/MRro3d), too. So the problem has to be elsewhere.  Like user253751 said, you have likely corrupted memory, and your `graph` is just the unwitting victim of it

Comment: @jspkay in `greedyAlgorithm()`, try changing `std::vector<int> colors{static_cast<int>(G.getSize())};` to `std::vector<int> colors(G.getSize());` and see if the problem still continues. You are again not setting the `vector`'s size to what you think you are.

Comment: @jspkay Also, in `main()`, `graph a = graph(10);` can be simplified to `graph a(10);` But more importantly, the `graph()` constructor should be using its [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to initialize `verteces`, and the `for` loop is completely redundant and can be removed: `graph::graph(unsigned long int n) : verteces(n), n(n) {}` In fact, you can get rid of the `n` member completely and just use `verteces.size()` when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even looking at the code, I added `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`<sup>1</sup> to compiler flags (to enable container bounds checks) and got this:

```
Error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 1, but 
container only holds 1 elements.
```

Then I used GDB to understand where exactly that happens:

```
void greedyAlgorithm(graph &G){
    std::vector<int> colors{static_cast<int>(G.getSize())};
    for(int i=0; i<G.getSize(); i++)
        colors[i] = -1; <-- HERE
```

This means that the syntax you used created a vector with a single element (with value `G.getSize()`).

This is why you should never EVER use [direct-list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (i.e. with curly braces, without `=`) with containers. If the vector had some other element type (not a number), this would've worked, and this is exactly why you shouldn't do it.

The fix is to use parentheses:

```
std::vector<int> colors(static_cast<int>(G.getSize()));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is libstdc++-specific flag (it only works with the GCC's standard library). Other standard library implementations have similar checks. There are also address sanitizers that could also work here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know there existed a difference between round braces and curly ones. My professor never explained something like that. I will go in deep about this

Comment: @jspkay You're welcome! Consider pressing the checkmark next to one of the answers to mark your question as solved.

Comment: You know, I don't have enough reputation yet... Sorry for that

Comment: @jspkay You don't need any rep to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> std::vector<int> colors{static_cast<int>(G.getSize())}
> ```

Constructs a vector with **one element** equal to `static_cast<int>(G.getSize())`. You want `std::vector colors(here_the_size)` not with `{` `}`. `std::vector colors(G.getSize());` will construct a vector with `G.getSize()` elements.

Because subsequent `colors[i] = -1;` overwrites memory without any checks, you get errors.

Use `.at()` instead of `[]`. Using `colors.at(i) = -1;` will allow you to detect errors early on.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know this difference!